# How to get list of updated contacts from ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

I am using `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback` to get notifications when the ios address book contacts changes.

How do I get list of updated (added/removed/modified) contacts from the callback? I do not wish to reload my entire list of contacts again.

I cant seem to find it anywhere in the documentation. Can anyone guide me, how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. What you could do is this which will give you a list of the contacts that were "modified in the time given" e.g. :

```
void MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback (ABAddressBookRef notifyAddressBook,CFDictionaryRef info,void *context)
{        
    //The addressbook object get's updated.


    CFArrayRef peopleRefs = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSource(notifyAddressBook, kABSourceTypeLocal);



    ABAddressBookRevert(notifyAddressBook);

    CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(peopleRefs);

    for (CFIndex i=0; i < count; i++) {
        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(peopleRefs, i);
        NSDate* datemod = (__bridge_transfer NSDate *)(ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonModificationDateProperty));


        NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:datemod];

        int seconds = round(distanceBetweenDates);

        if(seconds < 60){

            ABCPerson * person = [[ABCFacade sharedABCFacade] convertABRecordRef:ref];
            NSLog(@"modifactiondate: %@", [person modificationdate]);

            [[ABCFacade sharedABCFacade] replacePersonInPersonListWithPerson:person];

        }
    }


    NSLog(@"Yes it does get called by this change %@", context);

    [[ABCFacade sharedABCFacade] ABRefresh];   
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the only way then. Thanks.